# How to make my JFrame components dynamically scale when resizing the window, without hard-coding position and size values?

Tags: java, jframe, resize, window-resize

I'm learning java through university and I've been taught the basics of making a java program and designing GUIs. Maximizing a window after running my program makes all the JFrame components stay in place while grey fills the rest of the space. Here's an example of how it looks like:

[JFrame window normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f22Cz.png), [Maximized window before "fix"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXlcA.png).

After failing to find a solution I came up with a band-aid solution which is to get the component locations and just move them with hard-coded values when the jframe is maximized. This was not an elegant solution and every jframe in my java course project increased in the number of elements on screen. Is there any piece of code to make my components move and resize automatically and dynamically?

Here's what I've tried so far:

First I obtained the positions of components through 2D points:

```
Point managementLoginBtnLocation, empLogLocation, logoLocation, customerBtnLocation, welcomeLblLocation, contactBtnLocation, aboutBtnLocation, mainMenuBtnLocation;
//Constructor and rest of code...
public final void getOriginalComponentLocations()
    {
        managementLoginBtnLocation = managementLoginBtn.getLocation();
        empLogLocation = empLoginBtn.getLocation();
        logoLocation = shopLogo.getLocation();
        customerBtnLocation = customerBtn.getLocation();
        welcomeLblLocation = welcomeLbl.getLocation();
        contactBtnLocation = contactBtn.getLocation();
        aboutBtnLocation = aboutBtn.getLocation();
        mainMenuBtnLocation = mainMenuBtn.getLocation();
    }
//This method is called within the constructor.
```

I implemented the ComponentListener Interface and added a component listener to my jframe. Then I made it so when the jframe's size changes, it changes the size of the jlabel used for background art. And if the label's width is greater than 800 (the default I used while designing) it moves the components and doubles their size and font size. When the jframe is minimized the label will go back to the default size so I made a method to revert the font sizes, because I found the component sizes and locations reset automatically.

```
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
    {
//Resizing the background label and setting its icon to a resized version of its current icon.
        backgroundMainArt.setSize(this.getWidth() - 16, this.getHeight() - 21);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Program Files\\OMOClothingStore\\Resources\\Main menu\\main menu background art.jpg");
        Image img = icon.getImage();
        Image newImage = img.getScaledInstance(backgroundMainArt.getWidth(), backgroundMainArt.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_FAST);
        icon = new ImageIcon(newImage);
        backgroundMainArt.setIcon(icon);
        if(backgroundMainArt.getWidth() > 800) //When the size of the label is greater than default
        {
//I move the components, enlarge the buttons and zoom the font size
            moveComponents();
            enlargeBtns();
            zoomBtnsFontSize();
        }
        else //When the label is back to its original size
        {
//I revert the font sizes as button sizes and positions reset automatically
            revertBtnsFontSize();
            setLogoIconAndBackgroundArtAndWelcomeLbl();
        }
    }
public void moveComponents()
    {
        moveLogo();
        moveManagementLoginBtn();
        moveEmployeeLoginBtn();
        moveCustomerBtn();
        moveWelcomeLbl();
        moveContactInfoBtn();
        moveAboutBtn();
        moveMainMenuBtn();
    }
    public void moveLogo()
    {
        ImageIcon logoIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Program Files\\OMOClothingStore\\Resources\\Shared resources\\OMO Clothing Store logo.png");
        Image logoImg = logoIcon.getImage();
        Image newLogoImage = logoImg.getScaledInstance(250, 250, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        logoIcon = new ImageIcon(newLogoImage);
        shopLogo.setIcon(logoIcon);
        Point newLogoLocation = new Point();
        newLogoLocation.x = (logoLocation.x * 2) + 200;
        newLogoLocation.y = (logoLocation.y * 2) + 30;
        shopLogo.setLocation(newLogoLocation);
    }
//The rest of the "moveX" methods follow the same pattern as moveLogo()
public void enlargeBtns()
    {
        managementLoginBtn.setSize(410, 94);
        empLoginBtn.setSize(410, 94);
        customerBtn.setSize(410, 94);
    }
    public void zoomBtnsFontSize()
    {
        customerBtn.setFont(sizeBtn.getFont());
//sizeBtn is a JButton that has a font size of 24. I found that just creating a new Font object with bigger size here made the font way larger for some reason.
        empLoginBtn.setFont(sizeBtn.getFont());
        managementLoginBtn.setFont(sizeBtn.getFont());
    }
    public void revertBtnsFontSize()
    {
        empLoginBtn.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        managementLoginBtn.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        customerBtn.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    }
```

I split the moving of the components into many methods inside other methods because I found it easier to keep up with.
This worked. Here's how it looks like when running the JFrame: [Maximized window after "fix"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXINI.png). But moving on to other JFrames, they are more intricate and have many more components - extra buttons, panels with other components in them, menu bars, etc.
Is there a better approach to fixing this? Or do I just remove the ability to resize and move on?

Comment: Make use of multiple/compound layout managers

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you point me to a simple guide about layout managers? We didn't learn that in uni and I got really confused when looking it up myself 

Comment: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)